# SPRING remove row w/o page refreshing

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring

The following code is a part of a web app using spring framework. The html code involves a table row which when the checkout button is clicked will update the info in the database and remove that specific row. I am able to do all that but the page refreshes. How am i able to incorporate AJAX or other ways to prevent it from refreshing the page and still execute the task?

//html code

```
<td class="class-checkout-action-button">
                            enter code here<div>
                                <form th:action="@{/checkout/main}" th:object="${item}" method="POST">
                                    <button id="input-checkout-confirm" type="submit" name="action-admin" value="action-checkout-confirm" onclick="return checkConfirm(this)">Check Out</button>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="input-inventory-id" th:value="${item.id}"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

//javascript code for removing the row

```
function checkConfirm(o){
    var p=o.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (confirm("Check out?") == true) {
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

//Controller

```
@Controller
public class CheckOutViewController
{
    //Logging
    static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CheckOutViewController.class.getName());

    //Autowire Model
    @Autowired CheckOutViewModel checkOutViewModel;

    /**
     * Controller Mapping for Checkout Main GET
     * @param model Model
     * @return View Name
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    @RequestMapping(value= "/checkout/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String controllerCheckoutGET(Model model)
            throws SQLException
    {
        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Checkout/Main Controller GET");


        //Populate Session Attributes and Get Model
        return checkOutViewModel.setAttributeCheckoutMain(model);
    }

    /**
     * Controller Mapping for Checkout Main POST
     * @param model Model
     * @return View Name
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws MessagingException 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value= "/checkout/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String controllerCheckoutPOST(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            @RequestParam(value="action-admin", required=true) String action,
            @RequestParam(value="input-inventory-id", required=false) Integer id,
            @ModelAttribute InventoryItemSearch inventorySearch, BindingResult errors)
            throws SQLException, MessagingException
    {
        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Checkout/Main Controller GET");

        //Switch on Admin Action
        switch(action)
        {
            //Action: Check Search
            case "action_checkout_item_search":

                //Logging
                LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ":Admin Action for Item Search");

                //Get Model
                return checkOutViewModel.setAttributeCheckOutSearch(redirectAttributes, inventorySearch);

            //Action: Check Out Confirm
            case "action-checkout-confirm":

                //Logging
                LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ":Admin Action for Check Out Confirm");

                //Get Model
                return checkOutViewModel.setAttributeCheckOutSubmit(redirectAttributes, id);

            //Action: Check Out Cancel
            case "action-checkout-cancel":

                //Logging
                LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ":Admin Action for Check Out Cancel");

                //Get Model
                return checkOutViewModel.setAttributesCheckOutCancel(redirectAttributes, id);

            //Default
            default:

                //Logging
                LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ":Admin Action Default");

                //Get Model
                return checkOutViewModel.setAttributeCheckoutMain(model); 
        }
    }
}
```

//model

```
@Component
public class CheckOutViewModel 
{
    //Logging
    static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CheckOutViewModel.class.getName());


    //Autowired Item
    @Autowired InventoryItemDAO inventoryItemDAO;
    @Autowired InventoryItem inventoryItem;

    //Autowired Search
    @Autowired private InventoryItemSearch inventorySearch;

    //Autowire Email
    @Autowired MailUser mailUser;

    /**
     * Set Attributes for Inventory Main
     * @param model Model
     * @return View Name
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public String setAttributeCheckoutMain(Model model) 
            throws SQLException
    {
        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Set Attributes for Checkout/Main");

        //Check Model for Redirection
        if (UtilsModel.isModelEmpty(model) || model == null)
        {
            //Logging
            LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Get Inventory Pending Items and Set Login User");

            //Set Inventory List and Login User
            model.addAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.INVENTORY_LIST, inventoryItemDAO.getInventoryItemsPending());
            model.addAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.LOGIN_USER, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

            //Logging
            LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Reset Search, and Set Search List and Binding Search");

            //Reset Search, and Set Search List and Binding Search
            inventorySearch = new InventoryItemSearch();
            model.addAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY_BINDING, inventorySearch);
            model.addAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY, inventorySearch.getSearchList());
            model.addAttribute(AdminViewConsts.PAGE_TITLE, "Check Out");
        }

        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Return Model for Checkout/Main");

        //Set View Name and Return
        return "checkout/main";
    }

    /**
     * Set Attributes Check Out Search
     * @param redirectAttributes Redirect Attributes
     * @param itemSearch Item Search
     * @return View Name
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public String setAttributeCheckOutSearch(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            InventoryItemSearch inventorySearch) 
            throws SQLException
    {
        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Set Attributes for Checkout/Main Search");

        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Set Pending Inventory List, Login User, Search Binding and Search Attributes");

        //Set Inventory List and Login User
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.INVENTORY_LIST, inventoryItemDAO.getInventoryItemsPending(inventorySearch));
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.LOGIN_USER, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

        //Set Search List and Binding Search
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY_BINDING, inventorySearch);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY, inventorySearch.getSearchList());

        //Set Search Attributes
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SELECTED_SEARCH_INVENTORY, inventorySearch.getSearchInventory());
        if (!inventorySearch.getSearchField().equals("")) { redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_FIELD, inventorySearch.getSearchField()); }

        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Redirect to Checkout/Main");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(AdminViewConsts.PAGE_TITLE, "Check Out");
        //Set Redirect and Return
        return "redirect:/checkout/main";
    }

    /**
     * Set Attributes for Check Out Submit
     * @param redirectAttributes Redirect Attributes
     * @param id ID
     * @return View Name
     * @throws MessagingException 
     */
    public String setAttributeCheckOutSubmit(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, 
            Integer id) throws MessagingException 
    {
        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Set Attributes for Checkout/Main Confirm");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(AdminViewConsts.PAGE_TITLE, "Check Out");
        //Define Results
        int checkoutResults = -1;

        try
        {
            //Logging
            LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Confirm Inventory Item Check Out");

            //Get Inventory
            inventoryItem = inventoryItemDAO.getInventoryItem(id);

            //Confirm Reservation and Check Result
            checkoutResults = inventoryItemDAO.checkoutInventoryItem(id, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.MSG_STATUS, CheckOutViewMessage.getCheckoutCancelMessage(checkoutResults, inventoryItem));
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.INVENTORY_LIST, inventoryItemDAO.getInventoryItemsPending());

            //Check Results
            if (checkoutResults == 1)
            {               
                //Logging
                LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Check Out Successful, Send Email Notification");

                //Send Email Notification
                mailUser.sendMailCheckOut(inventoryItem, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
            }
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            //Logging
            LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": SQL Exception: " + e.getMessage() + " . Consuming Exception");

            //Report Exception Message
            String updateMessage = CheckOutViewMessage.getCheckoutMessage(checkoutResults, inventoryItem) + " " + e.getMessage();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.MSG_STATUS, updateMessage);
        }

        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Set Pending Inventory List, Login User, Search Binding and Search Attributes");

        //Set Login User
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.LOGIN_USER, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

        //Set Search List and Binding Search
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY_BINDING, inventorySearch);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY, inventorySearch.getSearchList());

        //Set Search Attributes
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SELECTED_SEARCH_INVENTORY, inventorySearch.getSearchInventory());
        if (!inventorySearch.getSearchField().equals("")) { redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_FIELD, inventorySearch.getSearchField()); }

        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Redirect to Checkout/Main");

        //Set View Name and Return
        return "redirect:/checkout/main";
    }

    /**
     * Set Attributes for Check Out Cancel
     * @param redirectAttributes Redirect Attributes
     * @param id Id
     * @return View Name
     * @throws MessagingException 
     */
    public String setAttributesCheckOutCancel(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, 
            Integer id) throws MessagingException
    {
        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Set Attributes for Checkout/Main Cancel");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(AdminViewConsts.PAGE_TITLE, "Check Out");
        //Define Results
        int checkoutResults = -1;

        try
        {
            //Logging
            LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Cancel Inventory Item Check Out");

            //Get Inventory
            inventoryItem = inventoryItemDAO.getInventoryItem(id);

            //Confirm Reservation and Check Result
            checkoutResults = inventoryItemDAO.checkoutCancelInventoryItem(id, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.MSG_STATUS, CheckOutViewMessage.getCheckoutCancelMessage(checkoutResults, inventoryItem));
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.INVENTORY_LIST, inventoryItemDAO.getInventoryItemsPending());

            //Check Results
            if (checkoutResults == 1)
            {               
                //Logging
                LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Check Out Cancel Successful, Send Email Notification");

                //Send Email Notification
                mailUser.sendMailCheckOutCancel(inventoryItem, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
            }
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            //Logging
            LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": SQL Exception: " + e.getMessage() + " . Consuming Exception");

            //Report Exception Message
            String updateMessage = CheckOutViewMessage.getCheckoutCancelMessage(checkoutResults, inventoryItem) + " " + e.getMessage();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.MSG_STATUS, updateMessage);
        }

        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Set Pending Inventory List, Login User, Search Binding and Search Attributes");

        //Set Login User
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(CheckOutViewConsts.LOGIN_USER, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

        //Set Search List and Binding Search
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY_BINDING, inventorySearch);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_INVENTORY, inventorySearch.getSearchList());

        //Set Search Attributes
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SELECTED_SEARCH_INVENTORY, inventorySearch.getSearchInventory());
        if (!inventorySearch.getSearchField().equals("")) { redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(InventoryItemSearchConsts.SEARCH_FIELD, inventorySearch.getSearchField()); }

        //Logging
        LOGGER.info(ConfigConsts.LOGGER_PREFIX + ": Redirect to Checkout/Main");

        //Set View Name and Return
        return "redirect:/checkout/main";
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing the submit button to a normal button

Comment: Also use Jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: after removing the submit type, only the javascript code executed, removing the row but no info was sent to the controller to execute the actually removal of info from the database. How do i use JQuery?

Comment: call form.submit() in your javascript. See sample document.getElementById('formId').action = "/youraction";
document.getElementById('formId').submit();

Comment: use jquery ajax as suggested by scary wombat. also change your controller method to return json object. convert this method to REST handler.